# F# adding an element to a list if it doesn't exists

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm starting to learn f# from scratch, and i'm finding myself quite confused with the difference between arrays and lists, I know lists are immutable but still.

I'm trying to create a function that adds an element to a list if it doesn't exists and return the new list, otherwise if it exists return the current list.

Here is what i have so far:

```
let elem x= Array.exists ((=) x)
let elemOrAdd e l = if elem e l then l else e::l
```

the e::l doesn't work, visual studio throws

```
This expression was expected to have type
    'a []    
but here has type
    'b list
```

I already find it a bit fishy that i have to use that Array.exists, but i truly am at a loss.

Any hints about what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.exists` gives your `elem` function the signature `x:'a -> ('a [] -> bool)`, which affects `elemOrAdd` definition assuming `l` type inferred an array, but used as a list. Changing `elem` definition to `let elem x= List.exists ((=) x)` will fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. But still, the distinction between array and list confuses me.

Comment: Concisely [`array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx) is a **mutable** fixed-size collection with operators `.` and `[]`
for direct access to any element, while [`list`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx) is **immutable** collection with operators `::` and `@`
allowing only sequential access to elements.

Answer (score 1):

In F# the `array` type is the `System.Array` type that you might remember from such languages as C#. The `list` type is an immutable [single-linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) that is part of FSharp.Core.

When you used `Array.exists` in your `elem` function the compiler inferred that the function expects `array` types, the compiler then inferred that your `elemOrAdd` function also expects `array` types. Which explains why, when you used `::` to attach an element to a `list`, the compiler complained. The `::` operator only works with `list` types.

Changing to use `List.exists` in your `elem` function will fix this.